# Looking for javascript event equivalent to 'onRender'

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to add to my `<td>` element JS event listener that will be triggered when the page is rendered (or loaded) to the DOM and the TD contains its innerHTML value.
something like:

```
<script>
function manipulate(field){
field.value = field.value+'_done';
}
</script>
<td onRender=manipulate(this)>Hello World</td>
```

I can't use **onLoad** because it can be used in `<body>` only to my understanding
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The "global" `onload` event triggers only after everything is loaded, and this includes your table cell. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the body's onload, it will fire when the complete page is ready and loaded. You can set an attribute for every TD element you'd like to manipulate, and then traverse the page to find those elements and call your function.

Why do you want to manipulate something after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: how can I find all elements in the page that contains a certain attribute in pure javascript (without JQuery for example)?

Comment: You can use document.getElementsByTagName to get all TD elements, and then compare the className for example

Comment: adding attribute to the element and searching for these elements in some init method is an accepted solution. Thanks

Comment: @Spiderman Depends which browsers you need to support. e.g. http://caniuse.com/queryselector allows you to easily look up elements with CSS selectors

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to attach the onLoad event to the body. You can use the global event handler like this:

```
function init() {
 //Your function call
}
window.onload = init;
```